# How to update Value of an specific cell in a Csv file from C# without affecting any other cell or rewriting the whole file

Tags: c#, csv

Using `WriteAllText` or `AppendAllText` is not serving the purpose. Could someone please help.
Thank you

Comment: Unless you are replacing the text with other text that is the same number of bytes, you can't. You have no choice but to read all the text and write all the text. Imagine the contents of a book printed using a fixed-width font. How could you change the text on one specific page when doing so would cause the entire contents after that point to reflow, possibly pushing text onto the next page or the previous page? What you want seems convenient but it's not how things work.

Comment: Thank you. Your first statement says that text is of same size. Yes in my case the cell is used as a Flag which is update from 0 to 1 and then 0 to 1. Could you please show an example.

Comment: You would have to know exactly where in the file the text is too. That means by bye, not by character. If you can confirm that you know that too, I'll add an answer that shows the how.

Comment: Suppose very minimalistic csv with two columns and one row, UpdateFlag1 and UpdateFlag2. Intially values are: UpdateFlag1: 1 UpdateFlag2: 2
and later after update
UpdateFlag1: 2 UpdateFlag2: 1

Comment: If we are to suppose that, why would we not suppose that you should just use `WriteAllText` or `WriteAllLines`?

Comment: Thanks for your generous help. To answer your question:  becasue I want to always change the value of only UpdateFlag2. If there are 10 fields, I want to change only one column value, all other column value should be unchanged.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. The standard way to modify a text file is to read the data in, modify as required and then write all the data out. Why can't you do that?